connecting live database locally
$servername = "***.***.**.***"; // IP address of the database server
$username = "databasemerge";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "mergingdatabase2-313935b733";

this is error i have with the cridentials i have provided upper
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond in C:\xampp\htdocs\mergingdata\livedatabaseconnect.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mergingdata\livedatabaseconnect.php(10): mysqli->__construct('185.151.30.164', 'databasemerge', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'mergingdatabase...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mergingdata\livedatabaseconnect.php on line 10
i have setup remote database access correctly
i have a rub host c panel and i want to conenct database locally please if any one have experience with rubhost c panel and remote access please helo me

You shouldn't post your DB credentials in a public forum...
